# Ansible playbook with_subelements

Tags: ansible

Ansible playbook with_subelements error with 3 levels.

My Config looks like

```
---
Firstlevel:
    - fl_number: fln1
      fl_data: fld1

      Secondlevel:
      - sl_number: sln_f1_1
        sl_data: sld_f1_1
        Thirdlevel:
        - tl_number: tln_s1_f1_1
          tl_data: tld_s1_f1_1
        - tl_number: tln_s2_f1_2
          tl_data: tld_s2_f1_2
```

The Ansible playbook is

```
>cat test_threelevels.yml
---
 - hosts: localhost
   gather_facts: no
   vars_files:
      - ../vars/testConfig-var.yml


tasks:

    - name: DebugWorks
      debug: msg="{{ item.1.Thirdlevel }}"
      with_subelements:
      - Firstlevel
      - Secondlevel

    - name: DebugDoesNotWork
      debug: msg=" Sub element Thirdlevel test"
      with_subelements:
      - Firstlevel
      - Secondlevel
      - Thirdlevel
```

When it is executed with 
    ansible-playbook -v test_threelevels.yml

the task "DebugWorks" works but the task "DebugDoesNotWork" dosent.

Output
    TASK: [DebugDoesNotWork]     ******************************************************
    fatal: [localhost] => subelements lookup expects a list of two items, first a dict or a list, and second a string

```
FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
```

Need help in understanding if this is the right way to do and why it does not work.

Open to any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error description at least vaguely says what's meant. :)

[Refer to the code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/d35b9569006be8b6fb2090b24969b678166386e2/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/subelements.py#L40) to see exactly the error means here. `terms` is the list you pass.

```
        if not isinstance(terms, list) or not 2 <= len(terms) <= 3:
```

In short: You can only go 2 levels, not 3.

[The documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements) does say clearly:

> Optionally, you can add a third element to the subelements list, that
>   holds a dictionary of flags.